# JSON in Rails 4 not contains all fields of object

Tags: ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I haven action in controller

```
def index
    if UserDatum.find_by_user_id(current_user.id) == nil
      redirect_to new_user_datum_path
    end

    @journal = Journal.new

    authorize! :read, @journals

    if params[:date]
      @journals = Journal.all.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} and DATE(created_at) = DATE('#{params[:date]}')").order("created_at DESC")
      @date = params[:date]
      return
    end

    @journals = Journal.all.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} and DATE(created_at) = DATE('#{Time.now}')").order("created_at DESC")

  end
```

And when I call it with param "date" it must return JSON (I use AJAX). But here's my JSON:

```
Object {id: 5, user_id: 31, systolic: 185, diastolic: 75, url: "http://localhost:3000/journals/5.json"} application.js?body=1:72
Object {id: 4, user_id: 31, systolic: 110, diastolic: 70, url: "http://localhost:3000/journals/4.json"} application.js?body=1:72
Object {id: 3, user_id: 31, systolic: 125, diastolic: 85, url: "http://localhost:3000/journals/3.json"} application.js?body=1:72
Object {id: 2, user_id: 31, systolic: 130, diastolic: 90, url: "http://localhost:3000/journals/2.json"} application.js?body=1:72
```

It must contains fields as 'created_at' and 'type_of_pressure'. But when I try to call them js returns 'undefinied'.

Comment: Can post what was the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things to mention.

1. It is not at all relyable to decide on the output type depending on request params. Rails provides the `request.format` to do that for all the routes in your app. So you need to use a `respond_to` block to define the output. Like this.

   ```
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { @journals = Journal.all.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} and DATE(created_at) = DATE('#{Time.now}')").order("created_at DESC") } 
     format.json { 
       @date = params[:date] || Time.now #set the default value just in case nothing was sent
       @journals = Journal.all.where("user_id = #{current_user.id} and DATE(created_at) = DATE('#{@date}')").order("created_at DESC")
     }
   ```

   Don't forget that this JSON will be served from `/journals.json` Set it correctly in your AJAX call.
2. To correctly format your JSON output you need to properly set up your `index.json` view. Of cource yu could render those journals directly from the controller action by calling `render json: @journals`, but the view is much more flexible. To customize the JSON views I prefer to use serializing tools like `jbuilder` (comes with Rails already). So open the `index.json.jbuilder` view in your `app/views/journals` directory and put there something like this:

   ```
   json.array! @journals do |journal|
     json.(journal, :id, :user_id, :systolic, :diastolic, :url, :type_of_pressure, :anything_else_you want)
   end
   ```

   Check out the [jbuilder docs](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) for more options and features.